# Show that function with compact support are integrable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show that measurable function with compact support are integrable. Can I do as following : Let $f$ with compact support. Then there is $K$ compact s.t. $supp(f)\subset K$. Then, there is $M$ s.t. $|f|<M$ (because the support is compact) and thus $$\int |f|<M\int_K=Mm(K)<\infty $$
where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Does it work ?

Comment: Your proof works for **bounded** measurable functions with compact support (in particular for continuous functions with compact support).

Comment: If you replace “measurable” with “continuous” then, assuming you're talking about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the bound $|f|<M$ can be stated. Just “measurable” is not sufficient.

Comment: @Surb Mark's function is definitely not continuous.

Comment: **Bounded** measurable functions with compact support are integrable, and the proof is as you wrote. On the other hand, unbounded measurable functions may not be integrable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not need to integrable eg.

$$
f(x) = 1/|x|,
$$
for $0 < |x| < 1 $ and 0 otherwise is not $L^1$.

Comment: its support is $[-1,1]$. For a point not to be in the support, the function has to be zero near it. So the support is always closed.